# Where can I find the cat litters

Tags: wasteland-2

In Wasteland 2, you are asked to retrieve cat litter in Los Angeles.

What are the locations of the cat litters for the quest asking you to retrieve them ?

Answer (score 4):

The locations are the following:

- Rodia: 3 bags.

  - Found on the farm in the extreme north-eastern end of the map, the uppermost level of the crater farms.
  - One in the sewers located in the bank near the vault.
  - The doctor in the hospital will give the player one bag in exchange for helping him find a cure for the plague (involves retrieving a microscope from the Angel Oracle and minor leg work in Rodia).
- Angel Oracle: 3 bags.

  - Two are found in the office of Mr Manners. He will allow the player to take them if they repair his toaster (or shoot him enough times that he stops caring).
    One is located in the steam tunnels, entrance is on the west side of the Colosseum. Kill roaches to reach the bag.
- Salt Lake Park: 1 bag.

  - In the area with the honey badgers, directly behind the farm, near the dung piles.
- Los Alamitos: 1 bag.

  - Found in the north after killing some Dugan's workbots.
- Long Beach: 1 bag.

  - Found in the alley next to the area taken over by Dugan's workbots.

[source](http://wasteland.gamepedia.com/Cat_litter_bag)

Although there are more then 7 locations, you can only find 7 in total.